# textbox size not changing with stylesheet

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, css

here is my css:

```
   <style type="text/css">
        .list-problems {
        height:600px !important;
        width:400px !important;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    .sizetextboxes {
        height:600px !important;
        width:400px !important;
        display:inline-block;
    }
```

the `.list-problems` is for a listbox and it works well! however i cannot get the `.sizetextboxes` to work! the textbox size is not being affected at all.

what am i doing wrong?

here's the complete code:

```
<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="EnterData.DataEntry.WebForm1" %>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <link href="../niceforms/niceforms-default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../niceforms/niceforms.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--The below is to make the calendar look nice!-->
    <link href="../jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .list-problems {
        height:600px !important;
        width:400px !important;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    .sizetextboxes {
        height:600px !important;
        width:400px !important;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    </style>



    <script>
        jQuery(function($) {
        //$("#occurrence_dateTextBox").mask("99/99/9999");
        //$("#<%= report_dateTextBox.ClientID %>").mask("99/99/9999");
        $("#<%= occurrence_dateTextBox.ClientID %>").datepicker();
        $("#<%= report_dateTextBox.ClientID %>").datepicker();
        //$(".datepicker").datepicker(); 

    });



    function getselectedproblems() {
        ob = document.getElementById('lstProblems');
        var problemlist = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < ob.options.length; i++) {
            if (ob.options[i].selected) {
                //alert(ob.options[i].value);
                problemlist = problemlist + ';' + ob.options[i].value; //Do something useful here
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("HiddenProblemList").value=problemlist;
    }

    </script>



</head>
<body><div id="container">
    <form id="form1" runat="server" class="niceform">

        <fieldset>

        <legend>Section A</legend>

        <dl>

            <dt><label for="occurrence_dateTextBox" >Occurrence Date:</label></dt>
            <dd><asp:TextBox ID="occurrence_dateTextBox" runat="server" size="50"/></dd>
        </dl>

        <dl>

            <dt><label for="report_dateTextBox">Report Date:</label></dt>
            <dd><asp:TextBox ID="report_dateTextBox" runat="server" size="50"/></dd>
        </dl>


        <dl>

            <dt><label for="spec_idTextBox">Specimen ID:</label></dt>
            <dd><asp:TextBox ID="spec_idTextBox" runat="server" size="50"/></dd>
        </dl>

        <dl>

            <dt><label for="batch_idTextBox">Batch ID:</label></dt>
            <dd><asp:TextBox ID="batch_idTextBox" runat="server" size="50"/></dd>
        </dl>

        <dl>

            <dt><label for="report_byTextBox">Report By:</label></dt>
            <dd><asp:TextBox ID="report_byTextBox" runat="server" size="50"/></dd>
        </dl>

        <dl>

            <dt><label for="identified_byTextBox">Identified ID:</label></dt>
            <dd><asp:TextBox ID="identified_byTextBox" runat="server" size="50"/></dd>
        </dl>

        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
        <legend>Section B</legend>



        <dl>
            <dt><label for="lstProblems">Problems List:</label></dt>
            <dd>
                <asp:ListBox ID="lstProblems" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" 
                    CssClass="list-problems" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Column1" 
                    DataValueField="Column1"></asp:ListBox>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LOM %>" 
                    SelectCommand="select '[' + category + ']' + ' ' + description from tblProblemList">
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </dd>

        </dl>  





        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
        <legend>Section C</legend>
        <dl>

            <dt><label for="section_c_issue_error_identified_byTextBox">Issue/Error Identified By:</label></dt>
            <dd><asp:TextBox ID="section_c_issue_error_identified_byTextBox" runat="server" size="50"/></dd>


        </dl>

        <dl>

            <dt><label for="section_c_commentsTextBox" >Comments:</label></dt>
            <dd><asp:TextBox ID="section_c_commentsTextBox" CssClass="sizetextboxes" runat="server" size="50"/></dd>


        </dl>       

        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
        <legend>Section D</legend>
        <dl>

            <dt><label for="section_d_investigationTextBox">Investigation:</label></dt>
            <dd><asp:TextBox ID="section_d_investigationTextBox" runat="server" size="50"/></dd>


        </dl>

        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
        <legend>Section E</legend>
        <dl>

            <dt><label for="section_e_corrective_actionTextBox">Corrective Action:</label></dt>
            <dd><asp:TextBox ID="section_e_corrective_actionTextBox" runat="server" height="200" TextMode="MultiLine" size="50"/></dd>


        </dl>


        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
        <legend>Section F</legend>
        <dl>

            <dt><label for="section_f_commentsTextBox">Comments:</label></dt>
            <dd><asp:TextBox ID="section_f_commentsTextBox" runat="server" size="50"/></dd>


        </dl>

        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
        <legend>Pre-Analytical</legend>


        <dl>
            <dt><label for="CheckBox1">PreAnalytical?</label></dt>
            <dd> <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false"
                            Visible="true" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged"/></dd>
        </dl>
        <dl>

            <dt><label for="prePracticeCodeTextBox">Practice Code:</label></dt>
            <dd><asp:TextBox ID="prePracticeCodeTextBox" runat="server" Visible="false"/></dd>


        </dl>

        <dl>

            <dt><label for="preContactTextBox1">Contact:</label></dt>

            <dd><asp:TextBox ID="preContactTextBox" runat="server" Visible="false"/></dd>


        </dl>

        </fieldset>


        <input id="HiddenProblemList" type="hidden" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="SubmitData"  OnClientClick="getselectedproblems()"/>


    </form>


</div></body>
</html>
```

here is the browser parsed code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head><title>

</title>


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <link href="../niceforms/niceforms-default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../niceforms/niceforms.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--The below is to make the calendar look nice!-->
    <link href="../jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .list-problems {
        height:600px !important;
        width:400px !important;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    .sizetextboxes {
        height:600px !important;
        width:400px !important;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    </style>



    <script>
        jQuery(function($) {
        //$("#occurrence_dateTextBox").mask("99/99/9999");
        //$("#report_dateTextBox").mask("99/99/9999");
        $("#occurrence_dateTextBox").datepicker();
        $("#report_dateTextBox").datepicker();
        //$(".datepicker").datepicker(); 

    });



    function getselectedproblems() {
        ob = document.getElementById('lstProblems');
        var problemlist = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < ob.options.length; i++) {
            if (ob.options[i].selected) {
                //alert(ob.options[i].value);
                problemlist = problemlist + ';' + ob.options[i].value; //Do something useful here
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("HiddenProblemList").value=problemlist;
    }

    </script>



</head>
<body><div id="container">
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="WebForm1.aspx" id="form1" class="niceform">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__LASTFOCUS" id="__LASTFOCUS" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="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" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>


<div>

    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="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" />
</div>

        <fieldset>

        <legend>Section A</legend>

        <dl>

            <dt><label for="occurrence_dateTextBox" >Occurrence Date:</label></dt>
            <dd><input name="occurrence_dateTextBox" type="text" id="occurrence_dateTextBox" size="50" /></dd>
        </dl>

        <dl>

            <dt><label for="report_dateTextBox">Report Date:</label></dt>
            <dd><input name="report_dateTextBox" type="text" id="report_dateTextBox" size="50" /></dd>
        </dl>


        <dl>

            <dt><label for="spec_idTextBox">Specimen ID:</label></dt>
            <dd><input name="spec_idTextBox" type="text" id="spec_idTextBox" size="50" /></dd>
        </dl>

        <dl>

            <dt><label for="batch_idTextBox">Batch ID:</label></dt>
            <dd><input name="batch_idTextBox" type="text" id="batch_idTextBox" size="50" /></dd>
        </dl>

        <dl>

            <dt><label for="report_byTextBox">Report By:</label></dt>
            <dd><input name="report_byTextBox" type="text" id="report_byTextBox" size="50" /></dd>
        </dl>

        <dl>

            <dt><label for="identified_byTextBox">Identified ID:</label></dt>
            <dd><input name="identified_byTextBox" type="text" id="identified_byTextBox" size="50" /></dd>
        </dl>

        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
        <legend>Section B</legend>



        <dl>
            <dt><label for="lstProblems">Problems List:</label></dt>
            <dd>
                <select size="4" name="lstProblems" multiple="multiple" id="lstProblems" class="list-problems">
    <option value="[LABELS] Specimen collection device mislabeled/unlabeled by practice">[LABELS] Specimen collection device mislabeled/unlabeled by practice</option>
    <option value="[LABELS] Specimen mislabeled: in-house error (Lab or DE)">[LABELS] Specimen mislabeled: in-house error (Lab or DE)</option>
    <option value="[TEST REQUISITIONS] Missing: no form sent with specimen">[TEST REQUISITIONS] Missing: no form sent with specimen</option>
    <option value="[TEST REQUISITIONS] Wrong (i.e. OT instead of ORAL - sister practice)">[TEST REQUISITIONS] Wrong (i.e. OT instead of ORAL - sister practice)</option>
    <option value="[TEST REQUISITIONS] Other: Non-ML">[TEST REQUISITIONS] Other: Non-ML</option>
    <option value="[TEST REQUISITIONS] Copies Received: New ID/Req. assigned">[TEST REQUISITIONS] Copies Received: New ID/Req. assigned</option>
    <option value="[TEST REQUISITIONS] Incomplete/Blank Requisition Form">[TEST REQUISITIONS] Incomplete/Blank Requisition Form</option>
    <option value="[TEST REQUISITIONS] 2 Specimens: 1 Req">[TEST REQUISITIONS] 2 Specimens: 1 Req</option>
    <option value="[TEST REQUISITIONS] 2 Reqs: 1 Specimen">[TEST REQUISITIONS] 2 Reqs: 1 Specimen</option>
    <option value="[VALIDITY ONLY] Need POC Results Confirmed">[VALIDITY ONLY] Need POC Results Confirmed</option>
    <option value="[VALIDITY ONLY] POC Results Marked Incorrectly">[VALIDITY ONLY] POC Results Marked Incorrectly</option>
    <option value="[VALIDITY ONLY] No Tests Ordered">[VALIDITY ONLY] No Tests Ordered</option>
    <option value="[VALIDITY ONLY] SEC A Unclear">[VALIDITY ONLY] SEC A Unclear</option>
    <option value="[SALES] Practice is not entered in database">[SALES] Practice is not entered in database</option>
    <option value="[SALES] CP has not been updated">[SALES] CP has not been updated</option>
    <option value="[OTHER] Other">[OTHER] Other</option>
    <option value="[REAGENT PROBLEM] QC Failure">[REAGENT PROBLEM] QC Failure</option>
    <option value="[REAGENT PROBLEM] QC Contamination">[REAGENT PROBLEM] QC Contamination</option>
    <option value="[REAGENT PROBLEM] Absence of INSTD">[REAGENT PROBLEM] Absence of INSTD</option>
    <option value="[INSTRUMENT PROBLEM] Liquid Handler #:">[INSTRUMENT PROBLEM] Liquid Handler #:</option>
    <option value="[INSTRUMENT PROBLEM] Olympus #:">[INSTRUMENT PROBLEM] Olympus #:</option>
    <option value="[INSTRUMENT PROBLEM] LC-MS/MS #:">[INSTRUMENT PROBLEM] LC-MS/MS #:</option>
    <option value="[PROCESSING PROBLEM] Aliquoting/Sample Processing">[PROCESSING PROBLEM] Aliquoting/Sample Processing</option>
    <option value="[PROCESSING PROBLEM] Specimen Contamination/ Carryover">[PROCESSING PROBLEM] Specimen Contamination/ Carryover</option>
    <option value="[PROCESSING PROBLEM] Plate Contamination">[PROCESSING PROBLEM] Plate Contamination</option>
    <option value="[PROCESSING PROBLEM] Blank Contamination">[PROCESSING PROBLEM] Blank Contamination</option>
    <option value="[DELAY IN PRODUCTION] Liquid Handler #:">[DELAY IN PRODUCTION] Liquid Handler #:</option>
    <option value="[DELAY IN PRODUCTION] Olympus #:">[DELAY IN PRODUCTION] Olympus #:</option>
    <option value="[DELAY IN PRODUCTION] LC-MS/MS #:">[DELAY IN PRODUCTION] LC-MS/MS #:</option>
    <option value="[OPERATOR ERROR] Operator Error">[OPERATOR ERROR] Operator Error</option>
    <option value="[DATA ENTRY] Medications ">[DATA ENTRY] Medications </option>
    <option value="[DATA ENTRY] Tests">[DATA ENTRY] Tests</option>
    <option value="[DATA ENTRY] Collection Date">[DATA ENTRY] Collection Date</option>
    <option value="[DATA ENTRY] Patient Name">[DATA ENTRY] Patient Name</option>
    <option value="[DATA ENTRY] DOB">[DATA ENTRY] DOB</option>
    <option value="[DATA ENTRY] SSN">[DATA ENTRY] SSN</option>
    <option value="[DATA ENTRY] Requesting Physician">[DATA ENTRY] Requesting Physician</option>
    <option value="[DATA ENTRY] Wrong Practice Code">[DATA ENTRY] Wrong Practice Code</option>
    <option value="[DATA ENTRY] Corrected Report û patient name &amp; all demos wrong">[DATA ENTRY] Corrected Report &#251; patient name &amp; all demos wrong</option>
    <option value="[PRACTICE ERROR] Medications ">[PRACTICE ERROR] Medications </option>
    <option value="[PRACTICE ERROR] Tests">[PRACTICE ERROR] Tests</option>
    <option value="[PRACTICE ERROR] Demographics">[PRACTICE ERROR] Demographics</option>
    <option value="[SALES SUPPORT/CLIENT REGISTRATION] Wrong Report Template">[SALES SUPPORT/CLIENT REGISTRATION] Wrong Report Template</option>
    <option value="[SALES SUPPORT/CLIENT REGISTRATION] Typo Practice Name or Physician">[SALES SUPPORT/CLIENT REGISTRATION] Typo Practice Name or Physician</option>
    <option value="[SALES SUPPORT/CLIENT REGISTRATION] E-mail Address">[SALES SUPPORT/CLIENT REGISTRATION] E-mail Address</option>
    <option value="[SALES SUPPORT/CLIENT REGISTRATION] Fax Number">[SALES SUPPORT/CLIENT REGISTRATION] Fax Number</option>
    <option value="[SALES SUPPORT/CLIENT REGISTRATION] Custom Profile entered incorrectly">[SALES SUPPORT/CLIENT REGISTRATION] Custom Profile entered incorrectly</option>
    <option value="[SALES SUPPORT/CLIENT REGISTRATION] Other">[SALES SUPPORT/CLIENT REGISTRATION] Other</option>
    <option value="[SALES] CP Update Needed">[SALES] CP Update Needed</option>
    <option value="[SALES] Client Education Needed">[SALES] Client Education Needed</option>
    <option value="[SALES] Other">[SALES] Other</option>
    <option value="[OPERATOR ERROR] Report Sent to Wrong Location/Physician">[OPERATOR ERROR] Report Sent to Wrong Location/Physician</option>
    <option value="[LAB] Corrected Report û reporting error">[LAB] Corrected Report &#251; reporting error</option>
    <option value="[LAB] Physician Requested Repeat">[LAB] Physician Requested Repeat</option>
    <option value="[LAB] Other">[LAB] Other</option>
    <option value="[QUIKLAB/MLIS PROBLEM] Quiklab/MLIS Problem">[QUIKLAB/MLIS PROBLEM] Quiklab/MLIS Problem</option>
    <option value="[PRACTICE COMPLAINT] Practice Complaint">[PRACTICE COMPLAINT] Practice Complaint</option>
    <option value="[SHIPPING] Shipping">[SHIPPING] Shipping</option>
    <option value="[BILLING] Billing">[BILLING] Billing</option>
    <option value="[OTHER] Other">[OTHER] Other</option>

</select>

            </dd>

        </dl>  





        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
        <legend>Section C</legend>
        <dl>

            <dt><label for="section_c_issue_error_identified_byTextBox">Issue/Error Identified By:</label></dt>
            <dd><input name="section_c_issue_error_identified_byTextBox" type="text" id="section_c_issue_error_identified_byTextBox" size="50" /></dd>


        </dl>

        <dl>

            <dt><label for="section_c_commentsTextBox" >Comments:</label></dt>
            <dd><input name="section_c_commentsTextBox" type="text" id="section_c_commentsTextBox" class="sizetextboxes" size="50" style="height:50px;" /></dd>


        </dl>       

        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
        <legend>Section D</legend>
        <dl>

            <dt><label for="section_d_investigationTextBox">Investigation:</label></dt>
            <dd><input name="section_d_investigationTextBox" type="text" id="section_d_investigationTextBox" size="50" /></dd>


        </dl>

        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
        <legend>Section E</legend>
        <dl>

            <dt><label for="section_e_corrective_actionTextBox">Corrective Action:</label></dt>
            <dd><textarea name="section_e_corrective_actionTextBox" rows="2" cols="20" id="section_e_corrective_actionTextBox" size="50" style="height:200px;"></textarea></dd>


        </dl>


        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
        <legend>Section F</legend>
        <dl>

            <dt><label for="section_f_commentsTextBox">Comments:</label></dt>
            <dd><input name="section_f_commentsTextBox" type="text" id="section_f_commentsTextBox" size="50" /></dd>


        </dl>

        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
        <legend>Pre-Analytical</legend>


        <dl>
            <dt><label for="CheckBox1">PreAnalytical?</label></dt>
            <dd> <span OnCheckChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged"><input id="CheckBox1" type="checkbox" name="CheckBox1" checked="checked" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'CheckBox1\',\'\')', 0)" /></span></dd>
        </dl>
        <dl>

            <dt><label for="prePracticeCodeTextBox">Practice Code:</label></dt>
            <dd><input name="prePracticeCodeTextBox" type="text" id="prePracticeCodeTextBox" /></dd>


        </dl>

        <dl>

            <dt><label for="preContactTextBox1">Contact:</label></dt>

            <dd><input name="preContactTextBox" type="text" id="preContactTextBox" /></dd>


        </dl>

        </fieldset>


        <input name="HiddenProblemList" type="hidden" id="HiddenProblemList" />
        <input type="submit" name="Button1" value="Button" onclick="getselectedproblems();" id="Button1" />


    </form>


</div></body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's only one occurence of `CssClass` at the moment (HTML). Did you forget to add the class to the other text boxes? If not, does a more specific selector (`#section_c_commentsTextBox`) produce the desired results? If not, can you show the parsed source code?

Comment: @rob my code as two occurrences here;s the second one:             <dd><asp:TextBox ID="section_c_commentsTextBox" CssClass="sizetextboxes" runat="server" size="50"/></dd>

Comment: @rob w when you say more specific can you show me what you mean?

Comment: The `id` (#) selector has a higher importance when selecting elements. Your CSS properties may be overwritten by other style (class) declarations. Post a link to the parsed ("browser view-source") code, and I might be able to find the cause of the issue within 10 minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text box in question has inline styling of `size="50"` and `style="height:50px;"`.  It seems like you actually want a TextArea here, not an input textbox.  I'm not familiar with ASP.NET, but adding this to the element might work `Wrap="true" TextMode="MultiLine"`.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="section_c_commentsTextBox" CssClass="sizetextboxes" runat="server" Wrap="true" TextMode="MultiLine"/>
```